# T-SQL Parsing XML escaped in format %3E (less than)

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am try to parse a string in xml format that has been escaped like below:

```
%3CRoot%3E%3CTMN%3E2014-10-23+10%3A00%3C%2FTMN%3E%3C%2FRoot%3E
```

In this example I would like to be able to grab the info between the TMN tags. (and convert the escaping so I can convert to a DateTime).

If possible I would like to do this in a select statement to avoid a while loop in my SP.

Comment: First off, convert this to XML usign a DecodeURL SQL or CLR function. Then it is standard XML parsing

Comment: Hi @gbn I tried a CLR solution with HTTPUtility.URLDecode - see below.  Unfortunately System.Web is not one of the supported libraries so there are some hoops to jump through to get it to work and some serious caveats about using unsupported assemblies.  Is there a more appropriate .net method you were thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to do it other than fixing up the strings, eg

```
DECLARE @yourString VARCHAR(MAX) = '%3CRoot%3E%3CTMN%3E2014-10-23+10%3A00%3C%2FTMN%3E%3C%2FRoot%3E'

SET @yourString = REPLACE ( @yourString, '%3c', '<' )   -- Replace 'less than' symbol
SET @yourString = REPLACE ( @yourString, '%3e', '>' )   -- Replace 'greater than' symbol
SET @yourString = REPLACE ( @yourString, '%2f', '/' )   -- Replace solidus (slash)
SET @yourString = REPLACE ( @yourString, '%3a', ':' )   -- Replace colon (:)
-- !!TODO any other codes eg http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

--SELECT @yourString ys
SELECT CAST( @yourString AS XML )
SELECT CAST( @yourString AS XML ).query('Root/TMN')
SELECT CAST( @yourString AS XML ).value('(Root/TMN)[1]', 'DATETIME')
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very detailed. I was afraid it would have to be something like this. It is going to make it a very long script due to the way the data is stored. I think I might just parse the raw string. Definitely going to save this script and that link for reference.

Comment: Just to update, I used a function in the end, I used `CHARINDEX` to grab the string between the tags and then used a very long list of `REPLACE`s to decode it.

Comment: I did create a CLR version using HTTPUtility.UrlDecode (with some help) over in dba.stackexchange, but I would be wary of using it giving the warnings from the guys over there:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81277/assembly-system-web-version-4-0-0-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-b03f5f7f1

Comment: @DJOldskool and wBob: just to be clear about that other CLR discussion, the warning was specific to `HTTPUtility` as it required importing `System.Web`, an unsupported .Net framework DLL, and there is no way to make it play nice with the highly restricted CLR host that runs inside of SQL Server. But, `Uri.UnescapeDataString` is fine as it can be done in a SAFE assembly since `System.Net` is a supported library. This is available for free via http://www.SQLsharp.com/ and would be used like: `SET @yourString = SQL#.INET_URIDecode(@yourString);`. Doing `REPLACE` requires _a lot_ of mappings ;-).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it in the end. To clarify my data is entered via mobile phone, placed in XML format then escaped using urlencode in java and sent to the database.

I am responsible for writing the reports.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Udf_EscapedXMLParse]
(
    @XMLString              VARCHAR(max)        = '',
    @requiredNode           VARCHAR(10)         = ''
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables here
    DECLARE 
        @StartData          INT,
        @Position           INT


    -- Find start of data between specified XML tags
    SET @StartData = CHARINDEX('%3C' + @requiredNode + '%3E', @XMLString) + 6 + LEN(@requiredNode)

    -- Remove the left side, then the right leaving just the required data
    SET @XMLString = SUBSTRING(@XMLString, @StartData, LEN(@XMLString) - @StartData)

    SET @XMLString = SUBSTRING(@XMLString, 0, CHARINDEX('%3C%2F' + @requiredNode + '%3E', @XMLString) )

    -- return value types that do not require escaping
    IF @requiredNode = 'NUM'
        RETURN @XMLString

    -- Convert the escaped text here
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%0A', '' )    -- Replace line feed
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%21', '!' )   -- Replace exclamation
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%22', '"' )   -- Replace speech marks
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%23', '#' )   -- Replace hash
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%24', '$' )   -- Replace dollar sign
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%25', '%' )   -- Replace percent
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%26', '&' )   -- Replace ampersand
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%27', '''' )  -- Replace single quote
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%28', '(' )   -- Replace left bracket
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%29', ')' )   -- Replace right bracket
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%2C', ',' )   -- Replace comma
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%2F', '/' )   -- Replace solidus (slash)
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3A', ':' )   -- Replace colon
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3B', ';' )   -- Replace semi colon
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3C', '<' )   -- Replace 'less than' symbol
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3D', '=' )   -- Replace equals sign
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3E', '>' )   -- Replace 'greater than' symbol
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%3F', '?' )   -- Replace question mark
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%40', '@' )   -- Replace commercial at
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%5B', '[' )   -- Replace square left
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%5C', '\' )   -- Replace backslash
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%5D', ']' )   -- Replace square right
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%5E', '^' )   -- Replace caret
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%7B', '{' )   -- Replace curly left
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%7D', '}' )   -- Replace curly right
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%7C', '|' )   -- Replace bar
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%7E', '~' )   -- Replace tilde
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%60', '`' )   -- Replace acute accent
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%A2', '¢' )    -- Replace cent
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%A3', '£' )    -- Replace pound sterling
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%A5', '¥' )    -- Replace Yen
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%A9', '©' )    -- Replace copyright
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%AE', '®' )    -- Replace registered
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C2%B0', '°' )    -- Replace degree
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C3%97', '×' )    -- Replace multiplication sign
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%C3%B7', '÷' )    -- Replace devision sign
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%CF%80', 'pi' )   -- Replace pi
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%E2%80%A2', '·' ) -- Replace middle dot
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%E2%82%AC', '€' ) -- Replace Euro
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%E2%84%85', 'c/o' ) -- Replace care of
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%E2%84%A2', '™' ) -- Replace trade mark
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%E2%88%9A', 'sqrt' ) -- Replace root symbol

    -- change +'s to space, then add any escaped +'s
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '+', ' ' )     -- Replace space
    SET @XMLString = REPLACE ( @XMLString, '%2B', '+' )   -- Replace plus sign

    -- Replace any other escaped characters with a space
    SET @Position = PATINDEX ( '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @XMLString )

    WHILE @Position > 0
        SELECT 
            @XMLString = STUFF ( @XMLString, @Position, 3, ' ' ),
            @Position = PATINDEX ( '%[%][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @XMLString )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @XMLString

END
```

I will come back to it another time as there are some optimisations I could make. Also adds two spaces for length 6 escaped chars and 3 spaces for length 9.

Comment: Understood. I was just trying to point out that using something like `SQL#.INET_URIDecode();` would reduce potential errors, not require constantly adding more REPLACE lines, and would likely be more efficient as well, especially since it does not prevent parallel execution plans like T-SQL functions do. And it is perfectly safe / secure. It's just an option to be aware of.